# How to place a variable value in string format of html text?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a requirement that I need to add a some values to the string format of *html* code which will be in sent to mail acts as unsubscribe link when I click on it it will go to some page. Here I have  variable want  to add is UrlVariable. this variable have already some value say for example organization. It has to append to the url. Lithe total url after appending variable value should be like this.

```
unsubscribe/asr/unsubscribe?type=organization.
   private String subscribeInfoContent = "<div style='margin-top:20px;'>
   <a href='sunny:8080/unsubscribe/asr/unsubscribe?type='unSubscribeUrlVariable'>
                Click here to unsubscribe from this newsletter.
   </a>
</div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add + operator to the string and variable.

```
private String subscribeInfoContent = "<div style=\"margin-top:20px;\"><a href=\"sunny:8080/unsubscribe/asr/unsubscribe?type="+unSubscribeUrlVariable+"\">Click here to unsubscribe from this newsletter.</a></div>";
```

Comment: i have tried it. it is printing like this in email:as it is<a href='http://sunny:8080/lms-unsubscribe/lms/unsubscribe?type=">Click here to unsubscribe from this newsletter.</a></div><div>

Comment: With HTML as text? Edit your question and post some more code when you're actually forming the whole mail to see if there's anything wrong.